# nested ul li categories function

Tags: php, arrays, tree

my categories table

```
ID,PARENT,NAME,ORDER
```

ul > li > li ... like this i want sort my data with php function.

first i want take all in array. after use function.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT ID,PARENT,NAME,ORDER FROM categories");

$category = array();

if(mysql_num_rows($query)>0){
    while ($rs= mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
        $category[$rs['PARENT']][$rs['ORDER']] = array('id'=>$rs['ID'],'name'=>$rs['NAME']);
}
```

After how can i print according **sortable** menu ?

```
<ul>
    <li>menu1
        <ul>
            <li>menu1a</li>
            <li>menu1b</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>menu2
        <ul>
            <li>menu2a</li>
            <li>menu2b</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>menu3
        <ul>
            <li>menu3a<ul>
                <li>menu3a_a</li>
                <li>menu3a_b</li>
            </ul></li>
            <li>menu3b</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use recurse(0, $category); instead of recurse(0, $categories);
and for every category you have to call this function.

Comment: yes, according category menu 

<ul>
<li>dede</li>
<li>dede</li>
</ul>

Comment: then what is the problem? I think you have to use recurse(0, $category); instead of recurse(0, $categories);

Comment: i used google translate. function i gave for example. how can i print menu according. (ul>li)

Comment: please elaborate what you want to ask.

Comment: i change question but i think very understandable. :)

Comment: i solved.

`function makeTree($parent, $categories) {
  if(isset($categories[$parent]) && count($categories[$parent])) {
    $output = '<ul'; if($parent==0) $output .= ' id="prCat"'; $output .= '>';
    ksort($categories[$parent]);
  foreach ($categories[$parent] as $category) {
   $output .= '<li><a href="#"'; if($parent==0) $output .= '  class="s_prct"'; $output .= '>' . $category['NAME'] . '</a>';
   $output .= makeTree($category['ID'], $categories);
   $output .= '</li>';
  }
  $output .= '</ul>';
  return $output;
 }
}
echo makeTree(0, $categories);`